# Mapstruct AnnotationProcessor with IntelliJ and Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotation-processing, mapstruct

I am trying to get the Mapstruct annotation processor to work in IntelliJ in a Gradle project.

Ideally, I would expect for all configuration to be in the gradle-file and that anyone could just import the project into IntelliJ and get a complete setup without having to set any preferences manually.

But I am okay with compromises on that.

I am using IntelliJ 2018.3 and Gradle 5.0 with Java 11 (i.e. the latest and greatest). The Mapstruct version is 1.2.0.FINAL.

What I have done:

- Configured the Mapstruct annotation processor in my `build.gradle`:

  ```
  compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:${mapstruct_version}"
  annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstruct_version}"
  ```
- Selected "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle" in the Preferences under "Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner"

In the directory `build/classes/java/main/com/myapp/mypackage/mapper/` I see a `MyMapperImpl.class` and a `MyMapperImpl.java`, so code generation seems to work.

Now I would expect that when I select my annotated abstract `MyMapper` class and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, that the generated `MyMapperImpl` appears in the hierarchy view.

If I manually mark `build/classes/java/main/` as a "generated sources" directory (which I really don't want to have to do, see above), the class still does not appear in the hierarchy. But the source code is marked with a lot of errors, as no classes from my project are found, apparently.

Needless to say: I can flawlessly run tests that use the mapper, both from IntelliJ and the command line.

Comment: Try this [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124090#focus=streamItem-27-2021191-0-0) using [Gradle idea](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124090#focus=streamItem-27-2021191-0-0), my team is also using mapstruct and we use it in our
**build.gradle**, you will need to bring the [`idea`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) plugin for gradle as well

```
def generatedSources = "$buildDir/generated"
def generatedOutputDir = file("$generatedSources")

/*
 create generated .java files in different folder than classes
 In IntelliJ 2016.3.x: Enable Annotation Processing, then set generated sources,
 relative to module output dir, at path '../../generated'
 */
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        generatedOutputDir.exists() || generatedOutputDir.mkdirs()
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '-s', "${generatedSources}"
        ]
    }
}


idea {
    module {
        downloadSources = true
        // tell intellij where to find generated sources
        sourceDirs += generatedOutputDir
    }
}
```

You will able to run your code even without `Gradle runner` with this workaround

Comment: I tried this and it solves one problem: The generated source code does not end up in the `build/classes` directory any more. But, IDEA still does not find the source code (even if I manually add the `build/generated` or the `out/generated` directory as "generated sources") and it is all red. Do I have to re-import my project? And do I have to select "Delegate ... to Gradle"?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a multi-module project. With the above snippet added to `subprojects`, IDEA adds all `generated` dirs as source directories to the root module. What I want is for them to be added to each module.