# Intellij is not picking mapstruct generated classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, mapstruct

I am trying to fix an issue with Intellij and Mapstruct.
Earlier I have used Java 8 and Gradle 4.6 and Mapstruct was working fine. Now I have upgraded Java to 11 and Gradle to 4.10.3. Now the problem is, after the build, when I run the application, I ended up with UnSatisfiedDependencyException because some Mapper class was not available. I have gone through many questions in SO, most of them suggested to delegate the Intellij build/run operation to Gradle. But I want Intellij to run the application and tests. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816022/mapstruct-annotationprocessor-with-intellij-and-gradle) post is suggesting the solution I want but after applying this, I am getting some different compile error.
This is a section from my build.gradle:

```
//mapstruct lib to generate mappings between Java bean types
compileOnly("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapStructVersion}")
annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapStructVersion}")

//lib to support lombok
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
```

Previously, the mapper classes was generated in src-->generated. Now after the upgrade, the mapper classes not generated in src->generated. Gradle generated classes are present in root-->build where I am able to see the mapper classes. Intellij is not picking the generated classes correctly or I am missing some config.
Please help me to fix the path correctly.
PS: I am using Intellij 2019.1.2 , Mapstruct 1.2.0.Final and Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE.

Comment: just for clarity, are your annotation processors enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452482/enable-annotation-processors-by-default

Comment: @EugeneKortov yes. Annotation processing enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `implementation` instead of `compileOnly` as it is in the official MapStruct examples:
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-on-gradle/build.gradle